# React: How to Child component re-render only prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I have:

```
function Parent(){
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({})
  return <div>
      <Child num={num}/>
    </div>
}

function Child({num}) {
  return <div>{num}</div>
}
```

I want `Child` re-render only `num` is updated. If only `someState` update, `Child` won't re-render.

Comment: That's not possible in this way, if you update the state of Parent, it will re-render Child. You can create a different component and add it under `<Child />`, and move `someState` into the new component, so that only the new component re-renders when you change the state.

Comment: I guess you can use React.memo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.memo and wrap your children component which you want to re-render only when props are changed.

Example:

```
import {useState, memo} from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({})

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setSomeState({id: 1})}>Change state</button>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Change num</button>
      <Child num={num}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = memo(function Child({num}) {
  console.log('child render');
  return <div>{num}</div>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a React component re-render only when its props changes, we need to use React `memo`.

```
import {memo} from 'react';

const Profile = (props) => {
 const {name, age, address, contact} = props;

 return <Name name={name}/>
};

const Name = memo(({name}) => {
 return <div>{name}</div>
});
```

In the above example, the component `Name` re-renders only when it's prop `name` changes. Even if the parent component `Profile` re-renders, `Name` will not re-render until it's prop changes